# Schedule Jenkins build with parameters with a twist

Tags: jenkins, build

I am using "build with parameters" and have a dropdown list with 10 different software modules, that are built.

Now I want to process this on a nightly basis.
In the end, I would like Jenkins to build every task in a rhythm of 15 minutes.
so at 0:00 task1 at 0:15 Task2 etc.

Do you guys have a suggestion?

1. a different "parent" Jenkins job, that triggers this job while iterating through an array.
2. perhaps a script that repeats the jobs and iterates through an array until it is done?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Nils, please be more clear about your problem. What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: What I understood till now is, You want your Jenkins job build Periodically and at the same time depending on another Jenkins Job...Right ?! (Comment, If I get it wrong)

Comment: Hi, I wnted to build periodically but everytime with a different parameter. I now used: "Build periodically with parameters" plugin

Answer (score 0):

Then, Probably You are talking about these two: 
- Jenkins Pipeline (https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/) 
- Periodic Build (https://nityanarayan44.blogspot.com/2017/11/jenkins-cron-job-scheduling.html)